# How do I expand to the definition of the negation of $\mathcal{P}(A)\subseteq \mathcal{P}(B)$ using quantifiers?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I know that $A\subseteq B\iff (\forall x)(x\in A\to x\in B)$. But how do I expand the powerset that way?

$$\mathcal{P}(A)\subseteq \mathcal{P}(B)\iff(\forall X)(X\in \mathcal{P}(A)\to X\in\mathcal{P}(B))$$

Now... how do I expand $X\in\mathcal{P}(A)$?

Comment: $\mathcal{P}(A)\subseteq \mathcal{P}(B)\iff A\subseteq B$

Comment: $x \in \mathcal{P}(A)$ just means that $x \subset A$.

Comment: @DominicMichaelis I need to prove that fact, but I don't know how to go about it.

Comment: $X\in\wp(A)$ iff $\forall x(x\in X\to x\in A)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the definition of powerset: $P(A)  = \{ X; X \subseteq A\}$

So:
$$X \in P(A) \iff X \subseteq A \iff \forall y:(y \in X \implies y \in A)$$

Therefore:
$$P(A) \subseteq P(B) \iff \forall X : (X \subseteq P(A) \implies X \subseteq P(B)) \iff $$
$$ \forall X : (\forall y: (y \in X \implies y \in A) \implies \forall y: (y \in X \implies y \in B))$$

The negation is as follows:
$$ \exists X :(\forall y: (y \in X \implies y \in A) \land \exists y : (y \in X \land y \notin B))$$

Using the rules: $\neg\forall X : \phi(x) \sim \exists X : \neg \phi(x) $ and $\neg(p \implies q) \sim p \land \neg q$.

Comment: $P(A)  = \{ X; X \subseteq A\}$

Comment: of course, my bad